# Pythonで2次元配列の行を、任意の条件に従って削除したい

Tags: python3, numpy

以下の2次元配列から "Yokohama"が含まれている行を削除したいです。

```py
arr = [
  ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
  ['Lemon', '30', 'Tokyo'],
  ['Lemon', '20', 'Osaka'],
  ['Lemon', '10', 'Yokohama'],
  ['Peach', '15', 'Tokyo']
]
```

np.deleteで削除しようとしましたが、うまくできませんでした。
1000万行ほどの処理に使うので、データ量に強い方法を教えていただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ユースケースが見えませんが、そういったクエリを継続的に発行するのであればリレーショナルデータベースの使用を検討しても良いと思いました。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。今回はpython内で完結できたので使用しませんでしたが、データ量が膨大になれば検討しようと思います。

Answer (score 1):

この記事 [Selecting rows from a NumPy ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1962980/9014308) の質問の2つ目のコードを参考にすると、以下の様に書けるのでは？ 1000万行までサポートできるか？ は不明ですが。

```
arr = arr[arr[:, 2] != 'Yokohama']
```

参考:

> If I wanted only rows where the second value is 4, it is easy:
>
> ```
> >>> test[test[:, 1] == 4]
> array([[ 3,  4],
>        [ 7,  4],
>        [16,  4],
>        ...
>        [81,  4],
>        [83,  4],
>        [88,  4]])
> ```

まとめると、以下の様になります。

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array((['AA','BB','CC'],
                ['Lemon','30','Tokyo'],
                ['Lemon','20','Osaka'],
                ['Lemon','10','Yokohama'],
                ['Peach','15','Tokyo']))

arr = arr[arr[:, 2] != 'Yokohama']

print(arr)

#以下は表示結果
#[['AA' 'BB' 'CC']
# ['Lemon' '30' 'Tokyo']
# ['Lemon' '20' 'Osaka']
# ['Peach' '15' 'Tokyo']]
```

Comment: 教えていただいた方法で解決しました。  ありがとうございます！